# Updating case classes from field-name strings and values

Tags: scala

Is there a less-verbose way to achieve this?

```
case class MyClass(
    a: A,
    b: B,
    c: C,
    ...
)

def updatedFromString(m: MyClass, field: String, value: String) = field match {
    case "A" => m.withA(value)
    case "B" => m.withB(value)
    case "C" => m.withC(value)
    ...
  }

implicit class FromStrings(m: MyClass) {
  def withA(v: String) = m.copy(a = A.fromString(v))
  def withB(v: String) = m.copy(b = B.fromString(v))
  def withC(v: String) = m.copy(c = C.fromString(v))
  ...
}
```

`MyClass` has a lot of fields - `a`,`b`,`c`, etc - all of which are instances of different case classes.
This leads to a lot of `case` statements above and a lot of updater methods named `withXXX`, which look fairly repetitive.

Comment: You may write a source generator to avoid writing the repetitive code.

Comment: Maybe Optics libraries can help here? (Not sure..)

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez by a source generator do you refer to the scala-macros? or do you something else in mind?

Comment: @GaëlJ Are you referring to the Monocle (https://github.com/optics-dev/Monocle) library? I looked into it - it seems more useful for nested structures. In my case, I just have one level. I feel I'll be introducing a lot a new words in the codebase, without reducing the lines-of-code significantly.

Comment: @ksceriath https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Generating-Files.html

Answer (score 2):

You could extract the logic:

```
// repetitive and generic enough to make it easier to generate
val setters: Map[String, String => MyClass => MyClass] = Map(
  "A" -> (v => _.copy(a => A.fromString(v)),
  "B" -> (v => _.copy(b => B.fromString(v)),
  "C" -> (v => _.copy(c => C.fromString(v)),
  ...
)

def updatedFromString(m: MyClass, field: String, value: String) = 
  setters(field)(value)(m)
```

If it is still too much, you could generate `setters` using macros or runtime reflection, but I am not sure it is worth the effort.

EDIT: An alternative solution which changes how you deal with code:

```
sealed trait PatchedField
object PatchedField {
  // field names corresponding to names from MyClass 
  case class FieldA(a: A) extends PatchedField
  case class FieldB(b: B) extends PatchedField
  ...
}

// removed stringiness and creates some type-level information
def parseKV(key: String, value: String): PatchedField = key match {
  case "A" => FieldA(A.fromString(v))
  case "B" => FieldB(B.fromString(v))
  ...
}

import io.scalaland.chimney.dls._

def updatedFromString(m: MyClass, field: String, value: String) =
  parse(field, value) match {
    // performs exhaustivity check
    case fieldA: FieldA => m.patchUsing(fieldA)
    case fieldB: FieldB => m.patchUsing(fieldB)
    ...
  }
```

If you don't like it... well, then you have to write you own macro, very obscure shapeless and/or codegen:

- there is no way you can generate `x.copy(y = z)` without a macro, even if some library does it, it does it using a macro underneath. At best you could use some lens library, but AFAIK no lens library out of the box would provide you a `Setter` for a field by singleton type of the field name (that is without writing something like `Lens[Type](_.field)` explicitly) - that I believe would be doable with some Shapeless black magic mapping over LabelledGenerics
- you might still need to convert `a` singleton type into `A` singleton type in compile time - that I am not sure if it is possible in Shapeless so you might need to push it down to value level, summoning a `Witness`, and then `.toUpperCase`ing it
- you would have to make each field aware of `Type.fromString` functionality - is it different for each field by its name or my its type? If the latter - you could use a normal parser typeclass. If the former, this typeclass would have to be dependently typed for a singleton type with a field name. Either way you would most likely have to define these typeclasses yourself
- then you would have to combine all of that together

It could be easier if you did it in runtime (scanning classes for some method and fields) instead of compile time... but you would have no checks that conversion actually exists for a field string to its value, type erasure would kick in (`Option[Int]` and `Option[String]` being the same thing, `null` no being anything).

With compile time approach you would have to at least define a typeclass per type, and then manually create the code that would put it all together. With some fast prototyping I arrived at:

```
import shapeless._
import shapeless.labelled._

trait StringParser[A] { def parse(string: String): A }
object StringParser {
  implicit val string: StringParser[String] = s => s
  implicit val int:    StringParser[Int]    = s => java.lang.Integer.parseInt(s).toInt
  implicit val double: StringParser[Double] = s => java.lang.Double.parseDouble(s).toDouble
  // ...
}


trait Mapper[X] { def mapper(): Map[String, StringParser[_]] }
object Mapper {

  implicit val hnilMapper: Mapper[HNil] = () => Map.empty

  implicit def consMapper[K <: Symbol, H, Repr <: HList](
    implicit
    key: Witness.Aux[K],
    parser: StringParser[H],
    mapper: Mapper[Repr]
  ): Mapper[FieldType[K, H] :: Repr] = () => mapper.mapper() + (key.value.name -> (parser : StringParser[_]))

  implicit def hlistMapper[T, Repr <: HList](
    implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, Repr],
    mapper: Mapper[Repr]
  ): Mapper[T] = () => mapper.mapper()

  def apply[T](implicit mapper: Mapper[T]): Map[String, StringParser[_]] = mapper.mapper()
}

val mappers = Mapper[MyClass]
```

Which you could use like:

- convert a field `String` to an actual field name
- extract a parser from the map using field name
- pass the value to the parser
- use runtime reflection to simulate copy or generate copy calls using macros

The last part simply cannot be done "magically" - as far as I am aware,  there is no library where you would require an implicit `Lens[Type, fieldName]` and obtain `Lens[Type, fieldName] { type Input; def setter(input: Input): Type => Type }`, so there is nothing which would generate that `.copy` for you. As a result it would require some form of manually written reflection.

If you want to have *compile-time* safety at this step, you might as well do the rest compile-time safe as well and implement everything as a macro which verifies the presence of the right typeclasses and things.

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't significantly reduce the lines of code. In my case, I ended up using the implicits because the size of the `updatedFromString` function exceeded the limits otherwise.

Comment: Another issue (also there in my code) - anytime someone adds a new field to `MyClass`, they should make corresponding changes to the `setters` map. Without an accompanying test, this can be easily missed. It would have been great if there was a way to get compile time safety for this. Using macros occurred to me, but given this is in Scala2.12, I want to keep those only as a last resort.

Comment: Sorry, but if you need to fully generate something that does `"_.copy(x = y)"` then you have to either write a macro or a codegen. If you moved parsing input and class name elseware, you could use `Patcher` functionality from Chimney. Then it could be done with some ADT and exhaustive match calling `myClass.patchUsing(concreteField)`.